# What is the rate limit for GCE instance metadata service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

On a GCP compute environment, I need to get an `id_token` (expires every 3600s) to make service-to-service authentication (using GCF, Cloud Run etc).

I get this id_token from the [instance metadata service](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/verifying-instance-identity#request_signature):

```
http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/identity?audience=[...]
```

Instead of implementing some form of caching+TTL for this identity token, I'm curious if I can call this endpoint every time I will make an outbound RPC (I might make a lot).

That's why I'm curious:

1. What's the rate limit for the instance metadata service?
2. Does the rate limit differ between GCE vs serverless platforms (GAE, GCF, Cloud Run)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Google Customer Service question and not a programming question. Contact the vendor directly for questions related to limits on their services.

Comment: @KenWhite I disagree a bit. This is commonly used product behavior. It's like asking what's the max file size on S3 (assuming it is not documented). Based on your approach, I'm not sure what sort of questions are valid for any vendor-specific tag.

Comment: You're not asking about use of the service. You're asking about rate limits in your first question, and a product comparison in the second. IMO, those are questions that can only be answered by the vendor, as SO can't speak about specific terms of use (limits, rates or charges, etc.) on behalf of an off-site vendor service.

Comment: @KenWhite - If programmers do not understand the resource they are using, their programs will often have problems. There is a grey area between writing code and writing code that interfaces with the computer/vm/service/API-call, etc. These types of questions should be allowed as they affect a programmer's ability to write good functional bug free code.

Comment: @JohnHanley: How does knowing the rate limit *affect a programmer's ability to write good functional error free code*? The rate limit is established by the vendor of the service, and that vendor is free to change use or terms of that service as they wish. We cannot speak to the terms or limits that Google sets for their products or services.

Comment: @KenWhite - If this topic is not discussed and not designed for, then the developer will write code that does not handle this case. Saying that the vendor controls this is the same as code that writes files. Should the programmer assume that the disk drive is limitless and ignore that a disk will fill up? There are concepts to API rate limiting that inexperienced programmers do not grasp. This is an important topic.

Comment: @JohnHanley: *disk drive*? That's a false comparision. Be realistic. Rate limits that can be controlled by a vendor service are hardly the same as disk I/O to hardware that is subject to physical limitations. If you're going to argue, at least have an argument that is logical and reasonable. This is twice you've come up with false facts in support of your argument. Rate limits neither affect the ability to write bug free code (*bug free code* is impossible in the first place) or compare to physical hardware limitations.

Comment: @KenWhite - I defer to you. This is just an argument with no future success.

Comment: So... What's the answer to OP's question?